# Change Value based on Dynamical Object

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Goal:
The goal is to make the variable with value '2014-06-14 09:00:00.000'.

Problem:
The syntax code is created as a dynamical object how do you make it from '2014-06-14 16:20:10.000' into value '2014-06-14 09:00:00.000'?

```
DECLARE @a datetime = '2014-06-14 16:20:10.000'
```

Information:
*The variable @a's value will be change all the time and the. The important is that "09:00:00.000" is not changeable.
*The value " 16:20:10.000' " can be different from time to time.

Comment: do you mean you want to change time?

Comment: are you meaning to strip the time component and add 9 hours to @a ?

Comment: Prashant16 - Yes.   g2server - No.  I have provided more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select dateadd(hour, 9, cast(cast(@a as date) as datetime))
```

Comment: Thank your for your help! The value of @a will be different in every time that '2014-06-14 16:20:10.000' can be for instance '2014-06-14 14:20:10.000'

Comment: @FullMetalGame Ok, how is that a problem. No matter what time you have it will come out as `09:00:00.000`. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/19135)

Answer (score 0):

Write as:

```
-- to get desired result the base query should be like:
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,'19000101',@a), CAST('09:00:00.000' AS DATETIME2(7)))
-- and then you can convert it into any other desired format as:
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),
               DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,'19000101',@a), 
               CAST('09:00:00.000' AS DATETIME2(7))),
               121);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: if `'09:00:00.000'` is always constant and the `date part alone differs`

```
DECLARE @a datetime = '2014-06-14 16:20:10.000'  
select @a  
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @a, 112))+'09:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @a DATETIME = '2014-06-14 16:20:10.000'
SET @a = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @a, 102),'.','-') + ' 09:00:00.000'
SELECT @a
```